# Strategies for identifying paternal DNA matches knowing only maternal matches

Tags: triangulation

I am adopted, my birth mother (deceased) was adopted, my birth father is unknown. Through research and DNA testing (Ancestry, 23andMe), I have learned that my birth mother gave birth to me, a sister (deceased) and a brother (untested), all with different fathers.

I have identified and confirmed a maternal half-niece and a maternal half-aunt (half sister to my birth mother and also adopted). I have identified my maternal grandmother (deceased) as well as a long line of maternal relatives through that maternal grandmother.

I am trying to come up with strategies to tease out who of the many relatives that I have are from my paternal line. I'm throwing this out to see whether triangulation might be a viable method, but with the large holes in my family tree and the number of deceased close relatives, I'm not sure if triangulation will help.

Looking for suggestions from folks with more experience in genetic genealogy than I have.